# How to update a single record using ASP.Net Web Api 1 with AngularJs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to update a  records in my project  but I'm stuck and wondering if I could get some help.

Angular Controller

```
$scope.userId = 1;
$scope.Age = 23;

$scope.updateRec = function(){

 var post = myservice.update($scope.userId, $scope.Age);
 post.then(function(data))
  return data;
 });
}
```

myservice js

```
this.update(id, age){
   var request = $http({
                method: 'put',
                url: '/api/updateuser/update/' + id,
                data: age
            });
            return request;

}
```

Api Controller

```
private context _db = new context();

[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
[HttpGet]
public bool Update(UserTable model)
{
    model.age = //<< here is where I'm stuck, how do I update the user's age here ?

     _db.SaveChanges();
     return true;
}
```

model

```
public class UserTable{
  public int userId {get:set;}
  public stringName {get;set;}
  public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to update the user's age by using the userId. but I'm stuck on how I receive the age from the client and update the database.
Could some direct me here please?

Comment: Added Entity Framework as that's where the actual question lies

Comment: You need to either tell your model that you've given it age, or change your parameters.  ajax: `data : { Age = age }`  or webapi:  `bool Update(int userId, int age)`.  Then add the code to update your EF db.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix several things in your code to achieve what you want:

**myservice.js**

```
function Update(params) {
    return $http.put('/api/updateuser/update/', params);
}
```

**Angular Controller**

```
//User object
$scope.userModel = {
    userId: 1,
    Age: 23
};  

$scope.updateRec = function(){

    //Call service passing parameters
     var post = myservice.Update($scope.userModel).then(function (response){

        return response;

     }, function (response) {
        //do something with error message..
     })

}
```

**API Controller C#**

```
[HttpPut]
public bool Update(UserTable model)
{
    //Get the user by Id
    var user = _db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.userId == model.userId);

    if(user == null)
        //Handle not existing user..

    //Change necessary Fields...
    user.Age = model.Age;

    //Commit changes
    _db.SaveChanges();

     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get an instance of your user. If you are using ASP.NET identity you can get using identity.GetUserById or something like this. After that you set the new age to the object. _db.SaveChanges should do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

1. First find the user to update from the database by ID.

Pseudo code example:

```
var user = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.UserId == model.userId);
```

2. Now you can update the users age and then call `SaveChanges()` to persist the changes to the database.

Pseudo code example:

```
user.Age = model.age;
_db.SaveChanges();
```